# Using MUI ThemeProvider causes "undefined" errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a small application I've made using MUI. It works fine, until I try to add a `ThemeProvider`. As soon as that is done, the application breaks, and all of MUI's components that I'm using start to throw `undefined`.

I'm trying to use `createTheme`, and have made sure to import it from `"@mui/material/styles"` as I know there's a similar package that has caused issues for others.

Here's my code:

```js
const light = {
  palette: {
    type: "light",
  },
};

const dark = {
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
  },
};

function App() {
  const [isDarkTheme, setIsDarkTheme] = useState(false);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={isDarkTheme ? createTheme(dark) : createTheme(light)}>
    // things
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

Then in my console I get errors like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'paper')`

Any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know if u still need it. I added a button, but u can use context or whatever u are using.

```
    import * as React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import {
      Button,
      ThemeProvider,
      createTheme,
      Paper
    } from "@mui/material";
    const light = {
      palette: {
        mode: "light",
      },
    };

    const dark = {
      palette: {
        mode: "dark",
      },
    };

    export default function App() {
      const [isDarkTheme, setIsDarkTheme] = React.useState(true);

      return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={isDarkTheme ? createTheme(dark) : createTheme(light)}>
          <Paper>
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                setIsDarkTheme(!isDarkTheme);
              }}
            >
              mode
            </Button>
          </Paper>
        </ThemeProvider>
      );
    }
```

This is your problem

```
    const dark = {
      palette: {
        //type: "dark" <---
        mode: "dark",
      },
    };
```

On a side note, this is how i would do it.

```
      export default function App() {
      const [isDarkTheme, setIsDarkTheme] = React.useState(true);

      const theme = createTheme({
        palette: {
          mode: isDarkTheme ? "light" : "dark"
        }
      });

      return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Paper>
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                setIsDarkTheme(!isDarkTheme);
              }}
            >
              mode
            </Button>
          </Paper>
        </ThemeProvider>
      );
    }
```

[image: Edit Usage (forked)]

Comment: Accepting this as the right answer. the `type` messed me up because that's what they still use in their official Theme Picker: https://bareynol.github.io/mui-theme-creator/ but looks like that's out of date

Comment: @crevulus Yes. With MUI v5 came a lot of change so I don't suggest looking at any examples before v5.